# Can't get navigation bar to display horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to display horizontally, but I'm not able to.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="theheader">
        <h1><a href="#">My Name</a></h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="subscribe">
            <li class="facebook"><a href="#">Follow on Facebook</a></li>
            <li class="rss"><a href="#">Subscribe by RSS</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#theheader {
    width: 961px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    #theheader h1 a {
        position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 376px;display: block; width: 208px; height: 213px; 
        background: url(Images/Welcome.png); text-indent: -9999px;
    }
        #theheader h1 a:hover {
            background-position: bottom;
        }

    #theheader ul#nav {
        float: left; margin: 22px 0 0 24px; list-style: none;
    }
        #theheader ul#nav li {
            float: left; margin: 0 0 0 45px;
        }
            #theheader ul#nav li:first-child {
                margin: 0;
            }
                #theheader ul#nav li a {
                    display: block; font: 13px Georgia, Serif; letter-spacing: 2px; color: #eeede6;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                    #theheader ul#nav li a:hover {
                        color: #d0cfc8;
                    }

    #theheader ul#subscribe {
        float: right; margin: 22px 24px 0 0; list-style: none;
    }
        #theheader ul#subscribe li {
            float: left; margin: 0 0 0 32px;
        }
            #theheader ul#subscribe li a {
                display: block; height: 16px; font: 13px Georgia, Serif; letter-spacing: 2px; color: #eeede6;
                text-decoration: none; padding: 1px 0 0 27px;
                background: url(images/icons.png) left 1px no-repeat;
            }
                #theheader ul#subscribe li.rss a {
                    background-position: left -16px;
                }
                    #theheader ul#subscribe li a:hover {
                        color: #d0cfc8;
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5AVA8/85/

I wanted the navigation bar to look something like this:

http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/blog-design-coded/demo/index.html#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the

```
<div class="theheader">
```

to

```
<div id="theheader">
```

because you specified a ID and not an class for the div Element.

Answer (score 2):

The handler you're using in your CSS '#' is used to handle ids such as `<div id="theheader">`

But here you have a class `<div class="theheader">`  so you can change it into an id or change all your '#' into '.' (used for classes)

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix to your problem is to replace `<div class="theheader">` to `<div id="theheader">`.

But I would rather change the css and replace the #selector with a .selector as this will make you class definitions reusable.